# How to use std::condition_variable with my own mutex wrapper

Tags: c++, logging, mutex, c++20, condition-variable

I wanted to demonstrate / log some `std::mutex` behaviour. I would like to log every call to `lock()` and `unlock()` (regardless whether they succeed or have to block). Originally, since those methods are not `virtual`, I tried to wrap the standard `std::mutex` in the following way, instead of using inheritance:

```
struct mutex_wrapper {
    std::mutex mut = std::mutex();

    void lock() {
        std::cout << "LOCKING MUTEX\n";
        mut.lock();
    }

    void unlock() {
        std::cout << "UNLOCKING MUTEX\n";
        mut.unlock();
    }
};
```

Ignore the fact that calls to `std::cout <<` could produce mangled output when called within multiple threads.

Then I wanted to inspect the output of a simple `std::condition_variable` example, as such:

```
int main() {
    auto ready = false;
    auto mutex = mutex_wrapper();
    auto cvar = std::condition_variable();

    auto t = std::thread([&mutex, &cvar, &ready] {
        std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
        cvar.wait(lock, [&ready] { return ready; });
        std::cout << "woke up\n";
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
        ready = true;
    }
    std::cout << "notifying\n";
    cvar.notify_one();

    t.join();
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't compile because, apparently, `wait()` requires that the corresponding `std::unique_lock` is instantiated with the regular `std::mutex` while I tried to use it with my own `mutex_wrapper`.

Is there any way to log the internal usage of locking and unlocking of a standard mutex? Or is there a way to make `std::condition_variable` work with wrappers?

Comment: AFAIK you'll either need [`std::condition_variable_any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any), since this works with any `BasicLockable` such as your custom muitex, or `friend`ship/some accessor to get the `std::mutex` out of your wrapped one

Comment: @Human-Compiler quoting cppreference, "*Whereas `std::condition_variable` works only on `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`, `condition_variable_any` can operate on any lock that meets the **BasicLockable** requirements*". This is definitely an answer, so please post one for me to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::condition_variable` only works specifically with `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` -- so you'll probably want to use  [`std::condition_variable_any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any). This is a generalization of `std::condition_variable` that can work with any `BasicLockable` type, such as your mutex wrapper.

Note that it may be a slight pessimization over using `std::condition_variable`/`std::mutex` directly since usually these are tightly coupled in the implementation for better performance. But since you're logging here anyway, I suspect this won't be that much of an issue overall.

An alternative approach is to write your own custom `condition_variable` wrapper that operates directly in terms of your wrapped `mutex` type and an underlying `std::condition_variable` -- and extract the `std::mutex` directly when locking.